# include_once is not executing php

Tags: php

I have done this a million times with no issue, but for some reason today, if I do this:

```
include_once('phpocr/config.php');
```

It doesn't execute the php in the file. it prints out the php code in the file. For all intents and purposes, just imagine that this is  the content of the file:

```
 <? class myClass {

 } ?>
```

And when I include that file, it literally prints out: "class myClass { }". Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you reinstall php? Did it install correctly?

Comment: something has turned of parsing of *.php in that particular directory?

Comment: Voted to close due to OP leaving out part of script from being seen which was cause of problem

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that the script that i'm using has the following opening tags

```
<?
```

My web server is set up to only accept

```
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you new to web programing ?

I guess that you're intent to run the php script through apache web server, all right?

If then you should set up the php module for apache as following

```
LoadModule php5_module /path/to/php5_module.so
```

With the above module, apache just regard the php script as normal text